# binding a property from Window to DataTrigger of a DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, binding

i have a boolean property and i want to binding it to datatrigger
 but my codes not work

i tried this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private bool _IsExist;

public bool IsExist
{
    get
    {
        return _IsExist;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsExist = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExist");
    }
}


private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string prop)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

and this way i can add items to datagrid and check if mypath exist or not so i need change property based on mypath exist or not

```
foreach (var i in parsedValues)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(MyPath)
    {
        IsExist = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsExist = false;
    }
    datagrid.Items.Add(i);
}
```

and this is my xaml

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="دانلود">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Button Click="Button_Click">
              <Button.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="Button">
                      <Setter Property="Content" Value="دانلود"/>
                      <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExist}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Content" Value="مشاهده"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
              </Button.Style>
          </Button>
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: yes,  `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }`

Comment: Is `IsExist` in `MainWindow`?

Comment: @Greg yes in mainwindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` looks for binding path inside of each item. So if your windows has the property, you simply can't access it like `Binding="{Binding IsExist}"`. This will only look into the `DataContext` of **each item** from the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`.

You need to tell XAML to look for the path in the `Window` not the cell:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=IsExist}"
```

This way, it goes up in the hierarchy until it reaches the first element with the type of `Window` and looks there for the given path.